# Output impedance of class C amplifier

Tags: amplifier, impedance

**Question**

- How to calculate the output impedance of a class C amplifier, considering that maximum efficiency is a priority?

**Explanation**

I found two strategies:

1. The first strategy is to observe the reflections of the amplifier (S22) and select matching circuit elements so as to eliminate them completely and transform calculated (measured) impedance to 50Ω. Exmaples: [link](http://www.rfcandy.biz/communication/blt53a.html)
2. The second option is to freely determine the output impedance, by using several steps:

   - define the output bandwidth (BW), and center frequency (fc) of the amplifier
   - calculate Q-value of the resonant LC circuit: $$Q=\frac{f_c}{BW}$$
   - choose C and L values of tank circuit that meet the equation: $$f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}$$
   - calculate output impedance of the amplifier (pure resistance): $$R_{out} = \frac{Q}{\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}}$$
   - calculate the needed supply voltage: $$V_{cc} = \sqrt{2R_{load}P_{out}}$$

Example: [link](https://youtu.be/gYbMpu4NoZo?si=WUPSLIU3G_TAX_U9&t=91)

Which method is more appropriate?

Comment: Why don't you simulate the problem and test your formulas out?

Comment: I would like to, but I don't have the transistor model. What's more, I'm asking here to get the opinion of someone experienced, because it may turn out that even if the efficiency is similar, there are other things that are important and that's why one of the options is not used, or what's more, none of them is optimal, and there is a better solution.

Comment: Piotr, the transistor model is important but, you appear to have neglected that in your 2nd proposed method. Hence the answer to your question (in the absence of performing simulations) has to be to measure it (your first proposal). But, your main question asks how to **calculate** it so, I'm at a loss.